# How to use a nickname to identify my posts?

Tags: support, new-users, display-names

I would like to use a nickname to identify my posts, not a user + number as shown when I log in.

How do I cause the log-in process to log me in as my nickname and not the user + number id (`user178183`) you have assigned?

Is this perhaps 'OpenIDs are wrongly identified'?

By the way, my nicknames are `intrader` or `mozillanerd`, depending on the occassion.

Comment: I have contributed in stackoverflow forum and my user name is still not as my chosen one: mozillanerd

Answer (score 4):

On your user profile, click the "edit" link and then fill in a name.

The edit link is in the center of the page, roughly top-aligned with your picture.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I have now done. I am identified as mozillanerd and my gravatar is a caffeine molecule

Answer (score 4):

Click on your username at the top of the page (or anywhere you see it), then click "edit" to change it to whatever you like.

However, note that usernames may only be changed once every 30 days.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I have now done. I am identified as mozillanerd and my gravatar is a caffeine molecule